# Cypress selecting item in list with .eq(0) also checks conditions in other items

Tags: cypress

How do I select one item of a list and apply the conditions to only that item?

I have this html:

```
  <ion-list v-if="mangelzuordnungs.length > 0">
    <ion-item>
      <h2>Item A</h2>
      <button
        data-cy="photo-add-button"
        shape="round"
      >
        <span data-cy="photo-add-button-text"> Hinzufügen </span>
      </button>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <h2>Item B</h2>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

And this test:

```
it('Ensures when Mangelzustand does contains photos, the "Hinzufügen" Button Text does not exist', () => {
    cy.get("ion-item")
      .eq(1)
      .get("[data-cy=photo-add-button")
      .get("[data-cy=photo-add-button-text")
      .should("not.contain", "Hinzufügen");
});
```

I would expect that the test succeeds because it fails arguing that `photo-add-button-text` exists and highlights the element of the first list item.

What am I missing?

Comment: `eq(0)` will return the first element on the list only. Which line is it actually failing for you ?

Comment: The last line `.should("not.exist");`. I have a list of 2 elements. The first element does not have the `photo-add-button-text` element, the second element has it. But because I get the first element I expect the test to succeed but I fails arguing that photo-add-button-text exists on the second item.

Comment: Can You share your Html dom ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `.get()` after `.eq(1)` you are searching from `cy.root()`, which is the the whole DOM.

Try `.find()` instead.

```js
cy.get("ion-item")
  .eq(1)
  .find("[data-cy=photo-add-button")
  .find("[data-cy=photo-add-button-text")
  .should("not.contain", "Hinzufügen");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second item in the list doesn't contain `[data-cy="photo-add-button-text]` and `[data-cy=photo-add-button-text]`, hence when you are trying to use `get()`, the test is failing. Instead you can directly assert:

```
cy.get("ion-item").eq(1).should("not.contain", "Hinzufügen")
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, however, KKahn's solution fits my needs better

Comment: Hey glad you were able to figure it out :)